# How can I view responses in Postman Collection Runner?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using the Postman Collection Runner to run the same request multiple times using iterations. My tests work as expected, but I'm not able to see the individual responses for each request.

Is it possible to view the responses for requests in the Postman Collection Runner?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This might help somebody, I tried

> pm.test(responseBody, true)

and this printed the response in run summary.

Comment: Looks good! Do you have hint how to print out also the requestBody?
pm.test(requestBody, true) is not working :-)

Comment: Hi @Dafka, 
To print request, you can use the request object like this, 

**pm.test(request.url, true);
pm.test(request.body, true);
pm.test(request.header, true);**

You can find more about the request object @ http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Request.html#~definition

Hope this would help. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 39):

In the latest version of Postman you can see all the data from the collection run for each individual request.

In the Collection Runner, Click on the request name and all the details of the request and response can be viewed.

[image]

More information can be going on the Debugging using the Request & Response body section of this [page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/debugging_a_collection_run)

Comment: Is there anyway to include those in the exported results?

Comment: Not in the UI export I don’t think, possibly running the collection through a Newman script? It’s not something I do so I would need to try it out. :)

Comment: Thanks Danny. I tried newman, but it's hard to know what data is available to the export template.

Comment: When I try this I get a message saying "Data unavailable (only data about the top 10 historical runs is stored).  The solution is to click the 'New' button at top right and re run the collection.

Comment: I believe that there is an open issue around this problem and will be addressed in future releases.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add more details about the **shadowcharly** solution.

Your results may be viewed if you assign `responseBody` variable to tests array (in `Tests` tab)

`tests["body"] = responseBody`

[image]

and **export it as json** (on the interface you only see the zero/one results if test passed or not).

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's not very useful but this is the only way I've found.

Comment: The given statement for test, returns a `{
     "name": "body",
     "status": "pass"
    },` in my output. Can you please suggest what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are repeating exactly the same query, you could use the test name to show the result:

```
tests['Test to see value of key Key'+ keyValue] = testResult....
```

You will have a different test for each value received, not exactly a log, but works fantastic ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but postman has added a feature in the collection runner. [image]

Comment: Its not saving the responses for me. Any idea what could be problem

Comment: @arqam Same here

Answer (score 0):

In my postman(Version 10.15.4) I can simply choose ***Persist responses for a session*** option on Collection Runner UI.

After that, you can click each test case and see the response body.
Please refer to the attachment screenshots.
[image]