# How to run one request from another using Pre-request Script in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to send an authenticated request with one click in postman.

So, I have request named "Oauth" and [I'm using Tests to store the token](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/) in a local variable.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.access_token);
```

What I'm trying to do now is that run the Oauth request automatically (from a pre-request script) for any other requests which needs a bearer token.

Is there a way to get an access token and send an authenticated request with one postman button click?

Comment: Related discussion on the postman github support page https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4193

Answer (score 70):

As mentioned by KBusc and inspired from those examples you can achieve your goal by setting a pre-request script like the following:

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: pm.environment.get("token_url"),
    method: 'GET',
    header: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxx==',
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    pm.environment.set("access_token", res.json().token);
});
```

Then you just reference `{{access_token}}` as any other environment variable.

Comment: how to run one of requests from my Workspace, eg just by name, from pre-request of any request i want?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question Dmitry but I suspect it is not strictly related to the original one and might have to do with new functionality added to Postman since then.. maybe opening a new question would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 27):

> NOTE: There now *is* a way to do this in a pre-request script, see [the other answers](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/). I'll keep this answer for posterity but just so everyone knows :)

I don't think there's a way to do this in the pre-request script just yet, but you can get it down to just a few clicks if you use a variable and the Tests tab. [There are fuller instructions on the Postman blog](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/), but the gist of it is:

1. Set up your authentication request like normal.
2. In the Tests section of that request, store the result of that request in a variable, possibly something like the following:

   ```
   var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", data.token);
   ```
3. Run the authentication request -- you should now see that `token` is set for that environment (click on the eye-shaped icon in the top right).
4. Set up your data request to use `{{token}}` wherever you had previously been pasting in the bearer token.
5. Run your data request -- it should now be properly authenticated.

To refresh the token, all you should need to do is re-run the authentication request.

Comment: I realize this is what the question was doing in the first place, but it's easy to search for the title not being aware of that XD

Comment: Thanks for the setting up my mind to the right way) Nowadays you'll get `Identifier 'data' has already been declared` running above code. To fix it we just need to rename variable `data` -> `body`

Answer (score 9):

You can't send another request from `Pre-request Script` section, but in fact, it's possible to chain request and run one after another.

You collect your request into collection and [run it](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/running_collections) with `Collection Runner`.

To view request results you can follow [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986276/3866610).

Comment: You actually can send request from the pre-request scripts : https://gist.github.com/madebysid/b57985b0649d3407a7aa9de1bd327990

Comment: @KBusc you might want to write that up as an answer!

Comment: Yes, you send a request from pre-request scripts as below:

pm.sendRequest("https://postman-echo.com/get", function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json());
    
});

Answer (score 8):

***First***, add pre-request script:

[image]

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://YOUR_SITE',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
        mode: 'urlencoded',
        urlencoded: [
            { key: "login", value: "YOUR_LOGIN" },
            { key: "password", value: "YOUR_PASSWORD" }
        ]
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err === null) {
        pm.globals.set("token", res.json()["access_token"]);
    }
});
```

***Second***, set custom variable(after you can use it value):

[image]

***Third***, you can use variable by `{{VARIABLENAME}}`, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The same question was on my mind, which is basically "how can I run another request that already exists from another request's test or pre-request script tabs without building that request with `pm.sendRequest(reqConfObj)`?", then I found the `postman.setNextRequest('requestName')` method from [this Postman discussion](https://community.postman.com/t/use-existing-postman-request-in-pre-post-script/23477) which is gonna lead you to [this postman documentation page](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/) about building request workflows.

But the thing is, `postman.setNextRequest()` method will not run if you are not running a folder or a collection, so simply hitting the 'Send' button of the request that has your script won't work.

I also would like to draw your attention towards some things:

- The prepended word, it's 'postman' instead of 'pm'.
- `postman.setNextRequest()` will always run last, even though you have written it to the top of your script. Your other code in the script will be ran and then `postman.setNextRequest` will initialize.
- If you would like to stop the request flow, you could simply `postman.setNextRequest(null)`.

I would encourage everyone that uses Postman to check out the links that was mentioned, I believe it's a great feature that everybody should give it a try! :)

Answer (score 5):

All these workarounds with recreating requests. Postman does not support what you want to do. In order to get what you want, you have to use Insomnia, it allows you to map body values from other request responses and if those responses are not executed ever it automatically runs them or behaves based on chosen policy.

But if you want to stick with Postman, then you'll have to save full previous request params to global variables, then retrieve all configuration of previous requests from that variable as a JSON string, parse that JSON into an object and assign it to pm.sendRequest as the first argument.

Comment: Thank you, this was the clarity I needed. To be clear, a lot of these other answers tell you how to recreate an existing request inside a Pre-request Script, but that is not the same thing as being able to call an already-existing request (in your Collection).

Answer (score 4):

You can add a pre-request script to the collection which will execute prior to each Postman request. For example, I use the following to return an access token from Apigee

```
const echoPostRequest = {
  url: client_credentials_url,
  method: 'POST',
  header: 'Authorization: Basic *Basic Authentication string*'
};

var getToken = true;

if (!pm.environment.get('token')) {
  console.log('Token  missing')
} else {
  console.log('Token all good');
}

if (getToken === true) {
  pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err ? err : res.json());
    if (err === null) {
      console.log('Saving the token');
      console.log(res);
      var responseJson = res.json();
      console.log(responseJson.access_token);
      pm.environment.set('token', responseJson.access_token)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting token in your auth token you can copy its request configuration to env once (in test script section) and automatically call it from other request and use token from env.

It originally mentuioned here: https://community.postman.com/t/use-existing-postman-request-in-pre-post-script/23477/5

1. Copy current request config to env in auth test script:

   let r=pm.response.json();

   pm.environment.set("access_token", r.access_token);
   pm.environment.set("refresh_token", r.refresh_token);

   pm.environment.set("auth_req", pm.request);

[image: save postman current request config to env]

And then call it on other endpoints:

```
pm.sendRequest(pm.environment.get("auth_req"))
```

[image: run postman request from env config]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but what I did when I wanted one function to run before another was this.
I added the below code to the pre-request script

```
 pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
    method: 'POST',
    header: 'headername1:value1',
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify({ key: "this is json" })
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
    // then called the other request here
    SecondRequest();
});

//Then I created a function 

function SecondRequest(){
    pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
    method: 'POST',
    header: 'headername1:value1',
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify({ key: "this is json" })
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
}
```

This is what I did, any reservations are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This works to me:

Authorization method *Test*:

```
pm.environment.set("auth-request", {
  parameters: {
    url: pm.request.url,
    method: pm.request.method,
    header: pm.request.headers,
    body: pm.request.body
  },
  callback: `(_, authResponse) => pm.environment.set("token", authResponse.json().token)`
})
```

Authorized endpoints *Pre-request Script*

```
const { parameters, callback } = pm.environment.get("auth-request")
pm.sendRequest(parameters, eval(callback))
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried multiple solutions, the below solution is related to when you are parsing the response for request 1 and passing any variable into the second request parameter. ( In this Example variable is Lastname. )

Note:- data and user are JSON objects.``

```
postman.clearGlobalVariable("variable_key");
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("variable_key");
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("enter the match string ");
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  var result = jsonData.data;
  var lastName = result.user.lastName;
tests["Body matches lastName "] = responseBody.has(lastName);
tests["print  matches lastName " + lastName ] = lastName;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function sendRequest of postman.

Some examples here.

https://gist.github.com/sid405/b57985b0649d3407a7aa9de1bd327990

Comment: the link has a 404