# Chaining postman requests - call postman request from another request?

Tags: rest, postman

I have two postman requests x,y which hit endpoints in two different rest api X,Y. x will give me an authentication token which is necessary to make the y request. How do I make the request x inside request y ? That is, call x from inside y.

PS - I have already figured out how to use request x to setup environment variables (auth token) which will be picked up by y.

Comment: No idea buddy but on StackOverflow you can open bounty if you got some reputation to get more attention (http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured). I will answer your question but in another place, because yours is duplicated :( (http://stackoverflow.com/q/39551635/3866610)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41986305/3866610 Hope it helps at least a little

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run one request from another using Pre-request Script in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551635/how-to-run-one-request-from-another-using-pre-request-script-in-postman)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it in one shot, you can use the pre-script option.

Pre-script are triggered before the request. So if you make a request and set the token in an environnement variable, the next call can use the token. You should check [that page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts). It seems outdated, you should replace `pm` by `postman`.

You might also want to add a pre script request to your collection. This way, every request of that collection will be precede by a request to the authentification route for exemple.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and best answer.  As an additional helping hand - to send a request in a "Pre-request Script" look up "pm.sendRequest"

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this:
https://blog.postman.com/conditional-workflows-in-postman/,
if you want to call a specific request from within a request,
the postman.setNextRequest() function will do the job.

Alexandre

Comment: the link seems dead :/
This one may be containing the same content ?
https://blog.postman.com/conditional-workflows-in-postman/

Answer (score 5):

The official documentation has you covered big dog - [Branching and looping](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/branching_and_looping/).

> When running a collection, you can branch and loop across API requests
>   in Postman using the `postman.setNextRequest("request_name");` function.

Then you use the collection runner to run the API requests in sequence.

Comment: how can I add the header from my previous response to the current request?

Answer (score 0):

Think about using [the Collection Runner](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/running_collections) to execute a sequence of requests.

Comment: Collection runner is created as a test tool. It will run every request of a collection and execute the tests associated with those. You might be able to trick this option but clearly, it is not the best way to do it.